# Ruby hash keys as object methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there an API or how would one go about creating hash keys being accessible by dot(.) methods like if there was Array of objects.

Here is an example :

```
data = [
  {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2'
  },
  {
    key1: 'valuex',
    key2: 'valuey'
  },
  ...
]
```

If I tried to do this :

```
data.collect(&:key1)
```

Would get this error :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `key1' for #<Hash:0x007fc2a7159188>
```

This however works :

```
data.collect{|hs| hs[:key1]}
```

Just because its a symbol and not object property. Is there a way I could accomplish same behaviour with symbols as if they were object properties?

Comment: It might be worth noting that `hs[:key1]` doesn't call a `key1` method on the hash but it calls the `[]` method with `:key1` as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is inspired by @spickerman's comment. It's something one can do but probably shouldn't do.

You can add your custom method to Ruby's Enumerable module:

```
module Enumerable
  def enum_send(:method, *args)
    send(:method) { |obj| obj.send(*args) }
  end
end
```

You can then call

```
data.enum_send(:collect, :"[]", :key1)  ## [value1, valuex..]
```

or something like

```
data.enum_send(:each, :delete, :key2)  ## [{key1: value1}, {key1: valuex}..]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap those hashes into `OpenStruct`. Try using this code:

```
data.map! { |hsh| OpenStruct.new(hsh) }

data.first.key1 # => "value1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your objects with [OpenStruct](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html)

```
require 'ostruct'

data.map { |it| OpenStruct.new(it) }.collect(&:key1)
```